# MVC custom filter that contains 2 Route attribute filters in it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to create a custom action filter attribute, that contains in it a declaration of 2 "RouteAttibute" filters.

I need:

```
[Contains2Routes]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Instead of:

```
[Route("~/index1")]
[Route("~/index2")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Thanks for the helpers!

Answer (score 0):

May be it is not the best way to do that, but you can achieve that with custom route attribute like that:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class MultiRouteAttribute : Attribute, IDirectRouteFactory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public string[] Templates { get; private set; }


    public MultiRouteAttribute(string[] template)
    {
        this.Templates = template;
    }

    RouteEntry IDirectRouteFactory.CreateRoute(DirectRouteFactoryContext context)
    {
        var template = "~/{Type:regex(" + string.Join("|", Templates) + ")}";
        IDirectRouteBuilder builder = context.CreateBuilder(template);
        builder.Name = this.Name;
        builder.Order = this.Order;
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

And you can use it like that:

```
[MultiRoute(new[] { "index1", "index2" })]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Instead of:

```
[Route("~/index1")]
[Route("~/index2")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

This solution is more limited than built-in `RouteAttribute`, because it is just using regexp in routes

Comment: First of all thanks, second, what if I want to add parameters, default values, and constraints?